# When using Spring Security, what is the reasoning behind pushing the Privileges into the database, rather than defining them programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working through an exercise at the moment in creating Fake Twitter using Spring Boot. The current part of the exercise involves the user authentication and security stuff.

In theory, I should create Users (entities), which have a many-to-many relationship with Roles (entities), which have a many-to-many relationship with Privileges (entities). allowing the creation and modification of Privileges at runtime.

Users have dynamic Roles, and Roles having dynamic Privileges, both make sense.

However, it seems like using Spring Security, I have to know the Privileges available at compile time, using either the @Secured annotation or a configured HttpSecurity.

What is the reasoning behind pushing the Privileges into the database, rather than defining them programmatically?

Comment: How else would you tie a privilige/role to a user? Do you want to hardcode your users as well?

Comment: @M.Deinum - My question isn't about tying the relationship between Users to Roles to Privileges in the database, nor even pushing the Roles into the database.

I'm specifically wondering about the 'why' of making Privileges Entities, rather than just Elements (either an enum or some other predefined set of constant values), owned by Role (such as via @ElementCollection).

(See also: https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration)

Comment: The `@ElementCollection` would also result in a db table. It all depends on your architecture. We had flexible roles and even allowed admins to create additional roles, based on permissions (what you call priviliges). If you only have a hardcoded set of roles, you might opt for hardcoding that configuration set of priviliges. Nonetheless you still need the flexible side of connecting the roles to users which would be in the database. So basicallly there is no straight nor easy answer as it depends.